# IIS 7 Authentication Configuration section is not supported

Tags: asp.net, authentication, iis, encryption

I have discovered that apparently even though encrypted identities are supported in ASP.NET (via encrypting in the web.config), IIS 7 will not allow you to change the authentication settings in the IIS Manager.  You get a message like this
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround for this is to temporarily comment out (using "<!-- -->") the identity section in the web.config and then IIS 7 Manager will allow you to view/modify authentication section.  Then remember to uncomment the section in web.config.